# Possible position of element in list using recursion?

Tags: scheme

Can anybody tell how to insert an element in the list in different positions and return a list of those possible combination as lists using `only recursion`?

For example, list is `(2 3)` and element to insert is `1`.

Output:

```
list(
    list (1 2 3)
    list (2 1 3)
    list (2 3 1)
)
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to determine what the output should look like, and in this case it should be a list of lists.
The second step is usually to break the problem down into cases of the input list.

The case of the empty list is pretty simple - the result is a list that contains one singleton list

```
(define (insert i ls)
    (if (null? ls)
        (list (list i))
        (...)))
```

For the case of the non-empty list, it's helpful to examine the structure of the expected result.

```
(insert 1 '(2 3)) 
-->
((1 2 3) (2 1 3) (2 3 1))
```

Note that only the first element of the result has `1` as its first element, and we can easily create this with `(cons 1 '(2 3))`.
The other elements all have the first element of the input list as their first element, and if you look at their tails, `(1 3)` and `(3 1)`, you'll see that they are the results of the recursion `(insert 1 '(3))`.
What's missing is that you need to `cons` the `2` onto each one of them afterwards.

Now we have all the necessary parts - in summary

```
(define (insert i ls)
    (if (null? ls)
        (list (list i))
        (cons (cons i ls) (<...something...> (insert i (cdr ls))))))
```

Where I've left a "<...something...>" part for you to figure out.